# Mysql select min in group of rows where userid=?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

This table stores data for who bought which book and when. I want to know which books were bought first by USERID #1. [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54e75/1)

That would result in

```
USERID  BOOKID  DATE_PURCHASE
1       2       2014-03-22 (purchased only by USERID #1)
1       5       2014-03-29 (purchased earlier than USERID #2)
1       6       2014-03-28 (purchased earlier than USERID #3)
1       7       2014-03-26 (purchased earlier than USERID #3)
```

It doesn't show BOOKID #3 because that book was purchased first by USERID #2.

Please note the table may consist tens of thousands of rows so I need an efficient solution.

If had to do it manually I would do this:

```
1. Check what books did USERID #1 buy
2. Go through all rows with those books (BOOKID) and check the MIN(DATE_PURCHASE) for each row
3. Write out those rows only where the USERID = #1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. By `this` and `this` is too broad, pls specify your need.

Comment: What if user #1 bought the book on the same day as user #2 (and nobody bought it earlier than that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter a [group-wise minimum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which itself is formulated using a self-join (in order to find the date of the first purchase of only those books bought by the desired user, irrespective of the purchaser):

```
SELECT * FROM docs NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   BOOKID, MIN(d2.DATE_PURCHASE) DATE_PURCHASE
  FROM     docs d1 JOIN docs d2 USING (BOOKID)
  WHERE    d1.USERID = 1
  GROUP BY BOOKID
) t WHERE USERID = 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54e75/3/0).